# Transform neo4j query result into graphjson like nodes & links in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, graph, neo4j

I’ve been using neo4j-driver in node-app to retrieve neo4j query result. I want to get this result in graph json (nodes & links) format to populate it in d3 just like this:
https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/5ZYS

But I’m getting the result in this format:
https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/FMJ1

I’ve tried some solutions to achieve this goal but no one was able to to it perfectly. Can you please guide me how to achieve it?

Here is my controller in node express app:

```js
import neo4j from 'neo4j-driver';
import {
  NEO4J_PASSWORD,
  NEO4J_URL,
  NEO4J_USERNAME,
} from '../../constants/index.js';
export const runMatchQuery = async (req, res) => {
  const query = req?.body?.query;
  if (query?.toLowerCase()?.includes('match')) {
    const driver = neo4j.driver(
      NEO4J_URL,
      neo4j.auth.basic(NEO4J_USERNAME, NEO4J_PASSWORD)
    );
    const session = driver.session();

    try {
      const result = await session.run(query);
      return res.status(200).json(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    } finally {
      await session.close();
      await driver.close();
    }
  } else {
    return res.send(405).json({ message: 'Query not permitted.' });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stream JSON to output for a list of nodes and relationships.

It's not the same format as you have, but it's pretty close with the nodes in a list and relationships in another list.

```
MATCH (n:MyNode)-[r:MY_REL]-()
WITH COLLECT(n) as mynodes, COLLECT(r) as myrels
CALL apoc.export.json.data(mynodes, myrels, null, {stream:True, jsonFormat: "JSON", writeNodeProperties:False})
YIELD data
RETURN data
```

Read more about the JSON output options at: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/json/

Comment: My use-case is such that we should not change the neo4j query. Rather we have to transform data generated from the query using our express code.

Comment: Ah, I see. To me, it looks like the JSON you're getting is based on part of the Neo4j movies database, and the JSON you want is based on Les Miserables. It's hard to tell how to transform the one to the other.